# Swap 2d Array Reference in function

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am trying to swap two 2d arrays, old and new.  I want to call a function, `copyNewToOld`, without actually copying the values.  I just want the reference to old to point to the location of new, and the reference to new to point to old.

So I can initialize like this:

```
float oldMesh[SIZE][SIZE] = {0};
float newMesh[SIZE][SIZE] = {0};
```

Invoke like this:

```
copyNewToOld(&newMesh, &oldMesh);
```

And implement in something like this:

```
void copyNewToOld(float *(new[][SIZE]), float *(old[][SIZE])){
    float **temp;
    temp = *new;
    *new = *old;
    *old = temp;
    temp = NULL;
}
```

However, that implementation does not swap the pointers, and I just continue to overwrite data over and over.

Am I missing something straight-forward?

Updated code:

```
float oldMesh[DIM + 2][DIM + 2] = {0};
float newMesh[DIM + 2][DIM + 2] = {0};
float **newTemp, **oldTemp
for(i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
  newTemp = &newMesh;
  oldTemp = &oldMesh;
  copyNewToOld(&newTemp, &oldTemp);
  calculateNew(newMesh, oldMesh, xsource, ysource);
}
```

with copyNewToOld as:

```
void copyNewToOld(float ***new, float ***old){
  float **temp;
  temp = *new;
  *new = *old;
  *old = temp;
}
```

Comment: Okay well two things. One, I was slightly mistaken; 2D arrays degrade to float*, not float**... fixing. Second, you need to set newTemp and oldTemp before the loop, and use them instead of *Mesh. Updating my answer with a fix to your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't change the pointer value of an array. You'll need four variables:

```
float oldmesh[SIZE][SIZE];
float newmesh[SIZE][SIZE];
float *oldMesh = (float*) oldmesh;
float *newMesh = (float*) newmesh;
void copyNewToOld( float **old, float **new ){
    float *temp = *old;
    *old = *new;
    *new = temp;
}
...
{
    copyNewToOld( &oldMesh, &newMesh );
}
```

A fix to your code:

```
float oldMesh[DIM + 2][DIM + 2] = {0};
float newMesh[DIM + 2][DIM + 2] = {0};
float *newTemp, *oldTemp
newTemp = (float*) newMesh;
oldTemp = (float*) oldMesh;
for(i = 0; i < iterations; i++){
  copyNewToOld(&newTemp, &oldTemp);
  calculateNew((float(*)[DIM + 2])newTemp, (float(*)[DIM + 2])oldTemp, xsource, ysource);
}
```

(The cast is for if you want the `calculateNew`function to receive a `float[DIM + 2][DIM + 2]`. If you don't mind doing the math on a 1D array, just pass in the `float*`)

Comment: Still not doing the swap... Not sure what I am doing wrong with that, but I agree that this solution should work.

Comment: @Joe Make sure you're not using `oldmesh` and `newmesh`. Use `oldMesh` and `newMesh`.

Comment: Yes I am using different names (mine are not so close together).  They still come back from the function un-swapped.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of swapping arrays, you should rather swap pointers to these arrays. 
If you want to swap the arrays directly, you have to copy their contents (with `memcpy` for instance).